# multiple inputs on x axis

Tags: graphing-functions

Please look at my table and graph below:

```
height  status
110         1
150         2
200         3
```

[image: table one]

Great, I have done three measurements. I input height of people and I have an Y axis, which represent a status. I inserted independent values on x and y the target data. I got this lovely scatter graph. Perfect.

Now my question is:

How do you apply multiple independent values to graph? Let's say I have:

```
height  weight  age status
110       50    10  1
150       100   20  2
200       200   30  3
```

for which I want to have all three independent values (height, weight, age) on X axis and status value on Y axis of course? What would be the correct way to place it in graph? I would really appreciate if you could help me understand that. Please be at least simplistic as possible. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: along same vertical line for each height also put in extra  red and green circles representing weight and age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each variable you want to plot, you need an axis. If you have four variables, you - in principle - need a four-dimensional space to plot in.

Well, that's of course no good, so what can we do? A common thing to do in these scenarios is to use the left vertical side of the plot as one axis and the right as another, [like this](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html).

But this allows only for three variables to be plotted at the same time. If you want, you could simply add a third dimension, but I wouldn't recommend it, as it becomes messy. Rather, I'd simply make two plot: Use the same $x$-variable on both and have two $y$-axis on one plot and a single $y$-axis (with the last variable) on the second plot.

Comment: Thank you Lovsovs, I was afraid the n-dimension is only solution, but indeed it's quiet messy:)